# Datatables.net for large data sets

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm reading http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html and their examples but this is seriously tough to follow. Even https://datatables.net/manual/server-side is light on the examples.

Before I go down this path so far that I can't turn back, can anyone who has used Datatables confirm the following for me:

1. I may end up having a large dataset with thousands of records; can I make it so initially only the first, say, 10 records are loaded. And then if the user hits the "Next page" button, records 11-20 are shown, and if they hit "Next page" again, 21-30 are shown, and so on? Loaded from the database (through a ajax/webservice) each time so its quick for the user.
2. Can I make it so the search bar searches through the entire dataset from the database? There's probably about 3 columns I'd need to be able to filter on (like username, email address, postal address).

If I can do both of these things, then Datatables can work for me. So if anyone who has experience with it can share their experience in regards to the above questions that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer both 1 and 2 at the same time: yes, this is exactly how the server side functionality works and it's pretty easy to implement. An object is sent to the server side component with information about what to search for and how many to return (equal to the number of elements you specify on a page at a time) and the response is a JSON object of only enough data to fit in one page. You simply set the following options when you create your datable

```
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "yourscript.php"
```

Check out the sample they offer here: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
Pull up chrome inspector/firebug and watch the network tab. You can see the payload being sent back and forth every time you page and search (datatables takes care of constructing this for you but it gives you a little bit of idea how exactly it works). On that same page you can see in the tabs the javascript that used to setup the datatable client side, then a php script thats used to setup the server side. For some reason the second server side script doesn't appear to be on that page but you can find it here: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

EDIT 1: to change the info text add this to your options:

```
language: {
        "info": "page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - for their own example at https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html; how do I know what the JSON returned by `"ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"` looks like? I tried various URL's on their site and I cannot find this php file anywhere.Basically I want to know what `json_encode(SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ))` returns because I don't want to use their classes. I'm using Symfony so I will leverage Doctrine instead, but I don't know how to format the JSON.

Comment: Ah... on that page look at the tab labeled 'Ajax'. It shows you the exact format that the response to the client needs to be in. EDIT: updated my answer to include link to the PHP class they're using. In case you wanted to see what there server side code looked like instead of trying to recreate what was in the 'Ajax' tab by hand.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. As for the searching part - how does that work? How do I make it known through code that I want to do a full search of all database records rather than just whatever has been loaded into the datatable at that point?

Comment: To answer your question as you posed it: you'll want to look for two GET variables... 'length' which is the max number of results on your table and 'search[value]' which contains the string to search for. So if you're using sql: `SELECT * FROM 'myDB' WHERE 'username' LIKE $_GET['search[value]'] OR 'emailaddress' LIKE $_GET['search[value]']  OR 'postaladdress' LIKE $_GET['search[value]'] LIMIT $_GET['lenght']` Is that by chance any more clearer? Theres some other stuff involved, but I'm just trying to show where to start out.

Comment: Thanks - your advice helped me immensely. I have been able to get it working :) If you could point me in the direction of how to change language strings, like making `Showing 51 to 71 of 71 entries` just `51 to 71 of 71 entries` I would be very grateful! I've found a few "legacy" documents about internationalisation but nothing recent.

Comment: Never mind above! Figured it out - just trying to figure out if I can replace the "Processing..." text with a spinner icon though

Comment: Great. So first I want to point out the "other stuff involved" I mentioned. If you haven't already come across this: study the link you posted about the variables being passed to the server https://datatables.net/manual/server-side. This is important because datatables passes some information about the "state" of the current view (like what column is being sorted and in what direction, what page it's on, etc...). You'll probably want to handle this on serverside unless you're *only* doing search queries. I see you figured out how to remove "Showing" but I've updated my answer for anyone else

Comment: I'm getting the hang of it now. I managed to get a spinning icon instead of the Processing... text and I've also got the sort working (including the direction as you mentioned). Do you know if it's possible to apply a row class? For example, if there's an "unapproved" record I'd want to highlight the row in red.I'm using bootstrap, so I can just add `class="danger"` but does Datatables have any provision for allowing that dynamically?

Comment: Yes, although its a little tricky. Lets assume the 'unapproved' field is a bool in your database. On the server side you'll want to make sure you always return the 'unapproved' for every record. On the client side you'll want to make sure to set up a column for 'unapproved' (you can use columnDefs to hide this in the actual display). Then you use the createdRow callback inside your datatable to test the value of unapproved in each row, if true then addClass('danger'). Example: https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow