# Improve highcharts performance for large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to get a larger amount of data. Sample data is below

```
1850/01   -0.845   -0.922   -0.748   -1.038   -0.652   -1.379   -0.311   -1.053   -0.636   -1.418   -0.272
1850/02   -0.043   -0.113    0.047   -0.244    0.159   -0.613    0.528   -0.260    0.177   -0.653    0.569
1850/03   -0.698   -0.794   -0.633   -0.891   -0.506   -1.123   -0.274   -0.910   -0.495   -1.174   -0.229
……….
2016/12    0.795    0.746    0.828    0.756    0.834    0.586    1.005    0.731    0.848    0.575    1.010
2017/01    1.025    0.977    1.067    0.983    1.068    0.786    1.265    0.963    1.084    0.778    1.271
2017/02    1.151    1.098    1.198    1.112    1.191    0.957    1.346    1.089    1.208    0.946    1.352
```

which starts from 1850 until 2017 and every month. I am processing this dataset to use it in Highcharts like this

```
$.each(lines, function(index, row) {
  var cells = row.split(','),
  series = {
    type: 'line',
    data:[]
  };

  $.each(cells, function(itemNo, item) {
    if (itemNo == 0) {
      series.name = item;
    } else {
      series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
    }
  });

  data.push(series);
});
```

And I use it in following way

```
chart = $('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    polar: true
  },
  series: data
});
```

This does work however, it is really really slow. How can I improve/enhance its performance so that I the highcharts gets loaded quickly without freezing the browser?

**UPDATE**
Here is my xAxis

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 12,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    },
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
yAxis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 2.2,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 2,
            width: 1,
            label: {
                text: '2°C',
                align: 'right',
                y: 2
            },
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            value: 1.5,
            width: 1,
            label: {
                text: '1.5°C',
                align: 'right',
                y: 30
            },
            color: 'red'
        }],
    },
```

Comment: maybe? - 
 https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/modules/boost.src.js

Comment: Already tries that one but no avail :-(.

Comment: Can it be delivered in chunks? Maybe a small node server to format it prior.

Comment: Actually, the whole data in one file and thats is. I get it from the file and process it so that it is useable by Highcharts.

Comment: Moreover, when use boost module it does display the graph quickly however, the lines are all stacked up on each other and all of them are out of place :(.

Comment: How about disabling markers? You have 2000points x 11series, so you have 22 000 of points on a chart. Rendering 22 000 of nodes (each marker is a separate node) takes time.

Comment: Consider resampling to simplify the amount of points in view at once, if your data allows it.

Comment: Any idea if the performance problem is in highchart or your js? Isn't preprocessing the file an option? (Server side or manual)

Comment: Well one of the options I am considering is that I want to push some of the data in data array and redraw those new data on highchart. Now how to do that is something I am expecting here mostly. If there is better approach then it is also welcomed.

Comment: pure js, minify code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574176/datatables-net-for-large-data-sets another option

Comment: are you not able to just cache the data object?

Comment: Cache concept is not there at all. Performance issue only lies at rendering time.

Comment: So you have 169 series which each has 11 points - which gives less than 2000 points for the chart (which is not many) - is it correct? I tried to replicate this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sm1r8e3f/ and the whole time needed for processing and rendering was below 1 sec. Can you adjust the fiddle to show the performance problems or set up a live example somewhere? - for now there is to few information to suggest enhancements. Besides, you can try to run the profiler in the browser and find the real bottleneck of the problem, creating and processing series is expensive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this problem will require a combination of the solutions proposed by others. These include:

1. **Condensing the data**: If I understand correctly, then you have 167 years of data and 12 months per year. Each of these will be a series, for a total of >2000 series. I'm not sure this will create an interpretable graph, but it's also likely I misunderstand the nature of your data and how you plan to plot it.
2. **Using the boost.js module of Highcharts**: Highcharts normally renders its graphs as SVGs. My understanding of the boost.js module is that it causes some parts of the charts to be rendered on HTML5 canvas elements. The HTML5 canvas is much faster than SVG for large numbers of data points. See an empirical comparison here: [SVG vs canvas: how to choose](https://jsfiddle.net/wxv72d61/)
3. **Setting chart options to minimize resource requirements**: I believe that the slowdown you're experiencing is unlikely to be due to the processing of your data. Rather, I think it's almost certainly due primarily to the rendering time required by Highcharts, and browser resources required to monitor events on all of the chart elements. By default, for instance, Highcharts plots allow you to "hover" your mouse over data points to highlight them, and they display tooltips with information about the data point. If you have a plot with thousands of data points, then this requires your browser to handle thousands of mouse events over the chart objects. Turning off this chart features should improve performance. In the demo below, I've turned off tooltips and data point highlighting using the mouse. I've also turned off the legend, to improve visibility of the chart.
4. **You can process and update the data in chunks**: In the long run, this will actually take more time than if you were to render the chunk all in one go, because Highcharts has to redraw the chart each time you add a new series. However, it might lead to a better user experience, since the page will appear more responsive. The demo below utilizes this type of approach. It allows you to set the number of lines of data to process per chunk (`linesPerChunk`) and the time delay between one chunk finishes processing and when you want to begin processing the next chunk (`timeBetweenChunks`). Ideally, `timeBetweenChunks` would be set to the time it takes Highcharts to render and display the last chunk, so that the computer alternates between processing data and rendering data, with no unproductive gaps in between. Ideally one could set this adaptively so that it's optimal across computers/users/browsers/etc., but I'm not sure how to do this; any ideas would be welcome. So for the moment it's just set to a constant 100 ms. With 2000 lines of data, 100 lines per chunk of data, and 100 ms between chunks, the whole thing should take ~2 s to load. The key function is `plotMoreData()`. After processing a chunk and adding the new series to the chart, it calls itself with a delay of `timeBetweenChunks` using `window.setTimeout(plotMoreData, timeBetweenChunks)`. It then redraws the chart. When `plotMoreData` gets called the next time, it processes the next chunk, and so on. It stops when it's processed and displayed all the data and also updates the status message.

EDIT:
It seems the Highcharts boost module does not work with polar charts, and this is a known issue. A fix is described here: [Polar Scatter Using Boost Module](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/polar-scatter-using-boost-module-t35679/). I was able to get this fix to work by modifying boost.src.js (built from [the Highcharts Github repository](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts) as follows:

At ~line 1380, I replaced:

```
if (!settings.useGPUTranslations) {
    inst.skipTranslation = true;
    x = xAxis.toPixels(x, true);
    y = yAxis.toPixels(y, true);
}
```

with:

```
if (!settings.useGPUTranslations) {
    inst.skipTranslation = true;
    // Default (non-Polar) calculation
    if( !series.chart.polar ) {
        x = xAxis.toPixels(x, true);
        y = yAxis.toPixels(y, true);
    }
    // Handle Polar chart coordinate conversion
    else {
        var polarPoint = {
            plotX: xAxis.translate( x, 0, 0, 0, 1, series.options.pointPlacement, series.type === 'flags' ),
            plotY: yAxis.translate( y, 0, 1, 0, 1 )
        };

        series.toXY( polarPoint );
        x = Math.round( polarPoint.plotX );
        y = Math.round( polarPoint.plotY );
    }
}
```

This seemed to work. See the demo here: [JSFiddle Polar Highcharts Boost Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wxv72d61/)

Comment: Thanks for such detail answer. The thing is that when I use boost module with polar chart(this solution is perfect for column chart) then the data shows just as dots and not lines anymore. Check my update for `yAxis` property.

Comment: @2619, See my edited answer for a possible workaround for the fact that Boost doesn't work with Polar charts. If you don't want to hack around on Highcharts, then your best bet is: 1) wait for the Highcharts developers to fix this problem themselves, or 2) move to a different charting package designed to work specifically with canvases. I know there are several, though I don't have any specific experience.

Answer (score 8):

Given the data you are displaying is not updating once a month, I feel like generating the chart for every view is a big waste of resources for your clients.

Indeed, it would be pretty easy for you to generate the chart without changing anything that you are doing now, but then extracting the resulting SVG and serving it simply to your visitors.

For that you simply have to use the [`getSVG`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.getSVG) method of HighCharts, that will return the SVG in a stringified form.

I don't really know if you want to have some sort of process to auto update the chart, but you could use a cron job for this purpose. Keep in mind that you would have to do something anyway even with your initial approach to update the data.

---

Regarding your script, first thing to notice is that you are using `$.each`, which is pretty bad in term of performance comparing to the vanilla equivalents. As demonstrated by this [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each/9), I get `3,649 Op/s` with `$.each` whereas for loops could get you up to `202,755 Op/s` which is insanely faster! Since you also doing a double loop, the difference would be `^2`.

But again, since the data is not updated often, this part of the script could be removed entirely and converted into a JSON corresponding to the output of the function, that HighCharts could load directly, skipping the entire processing and transformation of your CSV.

---

If using HighCharts is not a requirement, you could use [react-vis](https://github.com/uber/react-vis), which is a collection of React components focused around Data Visualization. It's build as an api on top of SVG, .

I've made a demo that you can [checkout on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyObzp?editors=0110) with the same data as you to plot the monthly temperatures since 1850.

```js
const {
  HorizontalGridLines,
  XAxis,
  XYPlot,
  YAxis,
  LineMarkSeries,
} = reactVis

const color = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1850, 2017])
  .range(['yellow', 'red'])

const Chart = () => (
  <XYPlot width={window.innerWidth - 100} height={window.innerHeight - 100}>
    <XAxis title='Month' />
    <YAxis title='Temperature' />
    <HorizontalGridLines />
    {Object.keys(data).map(key => (
      <LineMarkSeries color={color(key)} data={data[key]} key={key} />
    ))}
  </XYPlot>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Chart />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

I also use the `scaleLinear` method of [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3) to see the change over the years since I thought it would be an interesting information to show, but it can be changed depending of your needs.

[image: plot]

It's using SVGs, but we are also working on integration with webgl by the intermediary of [deck.gl](https://uber.github.io/deck.gl) which would allow for even more optimizations gains, still not ready yet and I'm not sure you would really need that much, but worth noting.

<sub>Disclaimer: I currently work for Uber, which made deck.gl and react-vis.</sub>

Comment: react is not an option :-(.

Comment: You could always create small component that will render your graph. I can also create an alternative using only d3?

Comment: Again Highcharts is the only library that needs to be used here :-(.

Comment: Understood! I updated my answer to reflect more approaches you could look into! ;)

Answer (score 1):

### `new Array(length)`

Specify the array's length rather than creating an empty array. Writing to an existing offset in an array is substantially faster than creating a new offset each time you write an item.

```
var data = new Array(lines.length);  // Specify array length

$.each(lines, function(index, row) {
  var cells = row.split(','),
  series = {
    type: 'line',
    data: new Array(cells.length)  // Specify array length
  };

  $.each(cells, function(itemNo, item) {
    if (itemNo == 0) {
      series.name = item;
    } else {
      series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
    }
  });

  data.push(series);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what is your choice for the xAxis, but if massaging the data in the server side is not an option what I would suggest is:

1. First do a call to load the data.
2. Show at spinning wheel where the chart is going to be displayed
3. Start parsing the dataset but don't load it all at once but in batches and redraw the chart as you parse the rest of the file.

This should avoid the freezing and give the visual indication that the data is being loaded.

**Edit:** Response to comment
I don't think is any longer an issue loading the data but on how to display the data in a meaningful way. Even if it loads in 2 seconds the result would be thousands of lines overlapping and totally unreadable.

You should default few hand picked values (ex Current month and same month and 1, 5, 10 years ago) and then allow the user to change the selection select up to a reasonable number of years/month (ex Compare July for 1980, 2010 and 2017) then plot those values updating the chart with (chart.series[0].update(....). 
There were no columns in the dataset so I assumed it was a column per month but I see now that they seem to be one per row and 11 columns represent some other data.

I don't think for a polar chart doing averages or doing rollups of the data is the best way to go but allowing to compare specific years and month with the exact data, whatever those values are :)

Comment: Point 3 is exactly what I am thinking too however, I tried it but I am not sure how to proceed with that approach. Any real example or code modification from above would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your xAxis? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
 var result = _.map(lines, function (row) {
    return { type: 'line', series: _.map(row.data, function (item, index) {
      if (index >= 1)
        return parseFloat(item);
    }), name: row.data[0]}
  });
```

(I'm writing this from my phone on a plane, so my apologies if there is are any typos or things I'm missing. Just trying to help!)

Comment: that means I would use `result` for `data` attribute in highcharts option. That means the whole data is first processed and then highcharts will be rendered. This would not enhance performance.

Comment: _.map is a performance increase over nested forEaches but I see what you're saying. Why not do this with chunks of 1000 records or so? Grab first 1000 and display results, then make a new variable and make a call to start the next. Once the new variable is not undefined, you can Union it with the current set and reassign it, and repeat until there are no more records left

Answer (score 0):

**Situation:**

I think the best and more appropriate solution would be to process and serve chunks of `data`, it would synchronize the display of points on your Chart and avoid loading the whole `data` once on document load, even if your data isn't as **large** as you described it in your post title.

But after reading your question, your comments and other posts, I can see that you are getting all data from one file, and you aren't processing data on server side so server side chunks is not an option for you.

**Alternative:**

Well if you can't process your data on server side why don't you process it on client side, HighCharts has two options for you:

- **Data grouping**:

  You can follow **[Highstock Demos › 52,000 points with data grouping](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping)**.
- **Lazy Async loading**:

  You can follow **[Highstock Demos › 1.7 million points with async loading](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading)**.

The both Demos show how to fetch data by ranges and limit the chart to display only relevant range data points, which will improve time loading performances.

Answer (score 0):

my team came across the similar problem but in our case we had 3 nested loops and when it was processing the data it was blocking the main thread which caused bad user experience. so i tackled this problem by deferring the processing data. which did the desired job of not blocking the main thread and did the processing much faster.

you can also use boost module developed by highchart (https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost/)