# .addPoint to multiple yAxis, freezes browser

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple [series](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.ad) being added to more than 1 [yAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis). Whenever I try to call `.addPoint` to anything other than the first yAxis, that browser tab's JS runtime freezes.

If I just add my series to the first yAxis, points successfully get added to the graph. The below approximates my code (in Clojurescript). Is there anything obvious I need to do to facilitate drawing to multiple yAxis(es)?

```
;; CHART SETUP
(def yaxis-config [{:title {:text "Y Axis: A"}
                    :height 200}

                   {:title {:text "Y Axis: B"}
                    :height 100
                    :top 300}])

(def series-config [{:name "Series A"
                     :id "series-a"
                     :yAxis 0
                     :data []
                     :tooltip {"valueDecimals" 2}}

                    {:name "Series B"
                     :id "series-b"
                     :yAxis 0
                     :data []
                     :tooltip {"valueDecimals" 2}}

                    {:name "Series C"
                     :id "series-c"
                     :type "arearange"
                     :lineWidth 0
                     :fillOpacity 0.3
                     :zIndex 0
                     :yAxis 0
                     :data []
                     :tooltip {"valueDecimals" 2}}

                    {:name "Series D"
                     :id "series-d"
                     :yAxis 1       ;; ** Only difference I notice
                     :data []
                     :shadow true
                     :tooltip {:valueDecimals 2}}])

(let [chart-options (clj->js {:title {:text "My Title"}
                              :yAxis yaxis-config
                              :series series-config})]

  (.stockChart js/Highcharts "container" chart-options))


;; ADD A POINT
(let [charts (aget (.-charts js/Highcharts) 0)

      series-a (aget (.-series charts) 0)
      series-b (aget (.-series charts) 1)
      series-c (aget (.-series charts) 2)
      series-d (aget (.-series charts) 3)

      data-a [1234567 112.5]
      data-b [1234567 123.11]
      data-c [1234567 155.7]
      data-d [1234567 0.257]]

  (.addPoint series-a (js/eval (clj->js data-a)) true false)
  (.addPoint series-b (js/eval (clj->js data-b)) true false)
  (.addPoint series-c (js/eval (clj->js data-c)) true false)

  ;; ** If I don't make this call, points are successfully added.
  ;; When adding this call, the JS runtime freezes and redraw stops.
  (.addPoint series-d (js/eval (clj->js data-d)) true false))
```

Comment: Hi Nutritioustim, I prepared and tested this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pwer9dho/ and everything works fine.

Comment: @ppotaczek Awesome. Thanks man. Your example is spot on. I just need to better manage performance.

Comment: I am glad I could help, please feel free to ask if you have any problems with Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The issue seems to be one of performance. I'm streaming a large amount of data, multiple ticks per second.

I fixed this issue by removing `:shadow true` (in `:id "series-d"`). From there, my streamed data successfully renders, albeit, very slowly.

The next order of business then, is to figure out how to *"garbage collect"* parts of a graph, or just boost performance.

- [Improve highcharts performance for large amounts of
  data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746529/improve-highcharts-performance-for-large-amounts-of-data)
- [Render millions of chart points with the Boost
  Module](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/higcharts-boost-module/)

Answer (score 0):

The `addPoint` method allows you to add point to series on a chart with multiple axes, for example in this way:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175].reverse(),
        yAxis: 1

    }],
    yAxis: [{}, {}]
});

chart.series[1].addPoint(2222);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pwer9dho/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Correct. My example has multiple axes. Apologies it's in Clojuerscript, so a bit unfamiliar. So I'm able to invoke the function like `(.addPoint mySeries myData true false)`, with less lag, if I omit the option for a shadow.